# jquerymobile HTML5 placing variable values in div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating a phonegap application, i have created a html5 page with subpages as DIV, however i am unable to put javascript calculated values in my result dash div. can anyone help me to solve this issue??

i want to put value of variable 'A' in div id - timetvA

variable raw in div id - timetvCPTM

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery-mobile/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit",function(){
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
});
</script>
<script>

function timesaving(){
var  A  ;
var B ;
var C ;
var D ;
var E ;
A  = document.getElementById('timeA');
B = document.getElementById('timeB');
C = document.getElementById('timeC');
D = document.getElementById('timeD');
E = document.getElementById('timeE');


var raw = C * (E / 100);
var     loss = (E * raw) / 100;
var     tech = raw + loss;
var     rraw = ttech * B;
var     tdum = rraw / C;

}
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="inputdash" data-role="page" data-theme="b" >
  <div data-role="header" >
    <h1>Calculations</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div align="center"><img src="images/iclogo.PNG" width="307" height="66" alt="logo"> </div>
  </div>
  <button >1 - Input Models</button>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
    <li><a href="#input1">Details<span class="ui-li-count">2</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#resultdash">
  <button data-theme="a" onClick="return timesaving();"> See Results</button>
  </a>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4 align="center">hello world</h4>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="input1" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header" >
    <h1>save</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-grid-a"><img src="images/iclogo.PNG" width="307" height="66" alt="logo"> </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" >
    <label for="timeA">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="timeA" id="timeA" value=""  />
    <label for="timeB">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="timeB" id="timeB" value=""  />
    <label for="timeC">weight kg:</label>
    <input type="text" name="timeC" id="timeC" value=""  />
    <label for="timeD">Hight:</label>
    <input type="text" name="timeD" id="timeD" value=""  />
    <label for="timeE">Pocket Money:</label>
    <input type="text" name="timeE" id="timeE" value=""  />

  </div>
  <a href="#inputdash">
  <button data-icon="arrow-r">Next</button>
  </a>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4 align="center">hello</h4>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="resultdash" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header" >
    <h1>Time Results</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-grid-a"><img src="images/iclogo.PNG" width="307" height="66" alt="logo"> </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <center>
      <h3>Name:
        <div id="timetvA"></div>
      </h3>
    </center>

    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible-set">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true">
        <h3>Play</h3>
        <div class="ui-grid-a" >
          <div id="timetvCPTM" class="ui-block-a" align="right" ></div>
          <div class="ui-block-b">&ensp; Minutes</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-a" >
          <div  class="ui-block-a" >1. candy crush: &ensp;</div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <div class="ui-grid-a" >
        <div class="ui-block-b" id="timetvICM">Home</div>
        <div id="timetvICMn" ></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-grid-a" >
        <div  class="ui-block-a" >1. home: &ensp;</div>
        <div id="timetvIC1" class="ui-block-b" ></div>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
      <h3>Class </h3>
      <div class="ui-grid-a" >
        <div class="ui-block-b" id="timetvICM">Time of play</div>
        <div id="timetvPAMn" ></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-grid-a" >
        <div  class="ui-block-a" >1. variable class: &ensp;</div>
        <div id="timetvPA1" class="ui-block-b" ></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-grid-a" >
        <div  class="ui-block-a" >2. variable: &ensp;</div>
        <div id="timetvPA2" class="ui-block-b" ></div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <h4 align="center">Hello world</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

```
A = $("#timeA").val();
B = $("#timeB").val();
C = $("#timeA").val();
D = $("#timeC").val();
E = $("#timeE").val();

$('#timetvA').append(A);
$('#timetvCPTM').append(raw);
```

## Updated code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <script>
  function timesaving(){
  var  A  ;
  var B ;
  var C ;
  var D ;
  var E ;

  A = $("#timeA").val();
  B = $("#timeB").val();
  C = $("#timeA").val();
  D = $("#timeC").val();
  E = $("#timeE").val();
  alert(A)

  $('#timetvA').append(A);
  var ttech = 1;
  var raw = C * (E / 100);
  var     loss = (E * raw) / 100;
  var     tech = raw + loss;
  var     rraw = ttech * B;
  var     tdum = rraw / C;

  $('#timetvCPTM').append(raw);


  }
  </script>
 <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="inputdash" data-role="page" data-theme="b" >
     <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>Calculations</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div align="center"><img src="images/iclogo.PNG" width="307" height="66" alt="logo"> </div>
     </div>
     <button >1 - Input Models</button>
     <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
        <li><a href="#input1">Details<span class="ui-li-count">2</span></a></li>
     </ul>
     <a href="#resultdash">
     <button data-theme="a" onClick="return timesaving();"> See Results</button>
     </a>
     <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4 align="center">hello world</h4>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="input1" data-theme="b">
     <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>save</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="ui-grid-a"><img src="images/iclogo.PNG" width="307" height="66" alt="logo"> </div>
     <div data-role="fieldcontain" >
        <label for="timeA">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="timeA" id="timeA" value=""  />
        <label for="timeB">Age:</label>
        <input type="text" name="timeB" id="timeB" value=""  />
        <label for="timeC">weight kg:</label>
        <input type="text" name="timeC" id="timeC" value=""  />
        <label for="timeD">Hight:</label>
        <input type="text" name="timeD" id="timeD" value=""  />
        <label for="timeE">Pocket Money:</label>
        <input type="text" name="timeE" id="timeE" value=""  />
     </div>
     <a href="#inputdash">
     <button data-icon="arrow-r">Next</button>
     </a>
     <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4 align="center">hello</h4>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="resultdash" data-theme="b">
     <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>Time Results</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="ui-grid-a"><img src="images/iclogo.PNG" width="307" height="66" alt="logo"> </div>
     <div data-role="content">
        <center>
           <h3>
              Name:
              <div id="timetvA"></div>
           </h3>
        </center>
     </div>
     <div data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true">
           <h3>Play</h3>
           <div class="ui-grid-a" >
              <div id="timetvCPTM" class="ui-block-a" align="right" ></div>
              <div class="ui-block-b">&ensp; Minutes</div>
           </div>
           <div class="ui-grid-a" >
              <div  class="ui-block-a" >1. candy crush: &ensp;</div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
           <h3>Home</h3>
           <div class="ui-grid-a" >
              <div class="ui-block-b" id="timetvICM">Home</div>
              <div id="timetvICMn" ></div>
           </div>
           <div class="ui-grid-a" >
              <div  class="ui-block-a" >1. home: &ensp;</div>
              <div id="timetvIC1" class="ui-block-b" ></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>Class </h3>
        <div class="ui-grid-a" >
           <div class="ui-block-b" id="timetvICM">Time of play</div>
           <div id="timetvPAMn" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-a" >
           <div  class="ui-block-a" >1. variable class: &ensp;</div>
           <div id="timetvPA1" class="ui-block-b" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-a" >
           <div  class="ui-block-a" >2. variable: &ensp;</div>
           <div id="timetvPA2" class="ui-block-b" ></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
     <h4 align="center">Hello world</h4>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: hello ved, i am still not getting the values, variable A is text string, rest all are decimal (long, double, float) values

Comment: @Monica I have checked your code its working and also get value of "A", I think something error in your javascript near var "ttech" now you can comment /*var raw = C * (E / 100);
var     loss = (E * raw) / 100;
var     tech = raw + loss;
var     rraw = ttech * B;
var     tdum = rraw / C;*/  line and after check my given code.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used jquery-mobile before, but some things to try - 1) All scripts should go at the bottom of the page, right before the body closing.  2) You don't need to close a script tag if you're just going to reopen it on the next line.  3) This wouldn't affect anything other than neatness, but you can define variables where they're initiated (i.e. var A  = document.getElementById('timeA');).

Again, not sure if any of that will help with your specific problem, but it will make your code better, at least.

Answer (score 0):

replace the following with your `timesaving` function

```
function timesaving(){
var  A  ;
var B ;
var C ;
var D ;
var E ;
A  = document.getElementById('timeA').value;
B = document.getElementById('timeB').value;
C = document.getElementById('timeC').value;
D = document.getElementById('timeD').value;
E = document.getElementById('timeE').value;


var raw = C * (E / 100);
var     loss = (E * raw) / 100;
var     tech = raw + loss;
var     rraw = tech * B;
var     tdum = rraw / C;

Atv = document.getElementById("timetvA")
Atv.innerHTML = A

cptm = document.getElementById("timetvCPTM")
cptm.innerHTML = raw
}
```

Comment: do i need to end statement with semicolon??

Comment: i have checked it but not getting any text in timetvA div

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#timetvCPTM').text(A);
```

or

```
$('#timetvCPTM').append(A);
```

to print out the var into the DIV